# Removing p_auth in liferay header (But not disabling the authentication check)

Tags: authentication, liferay, liferay-6

Is there a way to remove the p_auth in the POST header, but still having it in the body? I still required the authentication check, therefore disabling it is not the option. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this is an old question but there is no answer yet. You should enable friendly url mapping in Liferay. This involves creating a xml config file describing the url patterns and routes. You can find some information on it [here](https://www.liferay.com/en_GB/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/adding-friendly-url-mapping-to-the-portlet).

Once it is enabled you can specify the p_auth parameter to be hidden from the url.